Assumptions Wald's second equation?
Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables and $N$ an $\mathbb{N}_0$ valued random variable. Let $X_1 \in \mathcal{L}^2$ and $N \in \mathcal{L}^1$. Let $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\sigma^2:= \text{Var}(X_1), \ \mu:= \mathbb{E}[X_1]$. Wald's second equation reads
$$\mathbb{E}[(S_N - N\mu)^2] = \sigma^2\mathbb{E}[N]$$
It holds if $N$ is a stopping time w.r.t. to the natural filtration.
Now I have seen that it should also hold, if one only requires that $(X_k)_{k \geq n+1}$ and $\{N=n\}$ are independent for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Is this true?
The proof works if it is true that $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}, \{N=0\},\dots, \{N=k-1\})$ and $X_k$ are independent for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Why should this be true?
By the assumptions one knows that $X_k$ and $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1})$ are independent and also $X_k$ and $\{N=l\}$ for all $l=0,\dots,k-1$ (pairwise, individually). But why does it follow that $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1}, \{N=0\},\dots, \{N=k-1\})$ and $X_k$ are independent, so jointly? (also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4979670)
